# Open another tkinter program from a main file

Tags: python, tkinter

I have try this in my main program

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.filedialog
import os
root = Tk()
def open():
    PathPy = tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Open a file",filetypes=[('PYTHON file','.py')])
    os.system(PathPy)
B = Button(root, text="Open a file", command=open).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

and just this in my second file:

```
from tkinter import *
root2 = Tk()
root2.mainloop()
```

When I choose the python file, nothing happens... Can you please, tell me how to fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>Two additions to your code may give the expected result.</s>

[os.system](http://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system) expects a "command" for the operating system:

> Execute the command (a string) in a subshell.

like `python3 myscript.py`.

However, since you are using a custom python programming environment, pass the path of the [EduPython](http://edupython.tuxfamily.org/)'s `python.exe` to `os.system`:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.filedialog
import os
import sys

root = Tk()
pyexec = sys.executable

def open():
    PathPy = tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Open a file",filetypes=[('PYTHON file','.py')])
    os.system('%s %s' % (pyexec, PathPy))

B = Button(root, text="Open a file", command=open).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

<s>Second, add the last line `root2.mainloop()` to your second script to make the second Tk window appear.</s>

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sadly, nothing happend when I changed os.system(PathPy) to os.system('python ' + PathPy) and added at the last line root2.mainloop(), but thanks to have tried !

Comment: Hmm, sorry, my apologies it didn't work, I assumed it would work for you as same it worked for me. Do you use `python3`? How do you execute python from command line? I tested this in python2 as I don't have python3.

Comment: Yes, I use python3 because I work with a special software for my high school. If you can find informations, this the software I have to use: [Edupython](http://edupython.tuxfamily.org/)

Comment: Sounds good. Can you please give the output of `import sys; print(sys.executable)`?

Comment: `C:\Program Files (x86)\EduPython\App\python.exe` Thanks to take your time for helping me ! :) I'm sorry if I made mistake, my english is not perfect.

Comment: Great, thank you, I am very happy to help you, no worries your English is fine! (I don't know any francais :( ) .. I updated the answer, please try it :)

Answer (score 0):

As you are trying to execute a python file, use `execfile(file)`. But if all you want is a dialog, then use the `Toplevel` class.

To keep both windows running, use different threads. It's very easy to do in python.