# Launching a subprocess by pressing a tkinter button

Tags: python, tkinter, callback, subprocess

I am currently brand new to to Python and coding in general, just wanted to try and make a layout of 4 buttons open different programs when clicked. As of right now my code looks as follow.

```
from tkinter import *
import os
import subprocess
root=Tk()
root.geometry('750x650')
root.title('Test')
topFrame = Frame(root)
topFrame.pack(side=TOP, fill='both')
bottomFrame = Frame(root)
bottomFrame.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill='both')


button1 = Button(topFrame, text="Button1", fg="black")
button2 = Button(topFrame, text="Button2", fg="black")
button3 = Button(bottomFrame, text="Button3", fg="black")
button4 = Button(bottomFrame, text="Button4", fg="black")
button1.config(height=21, width=52)
button2.config(height=21, width=52)
button3.config(height=21, width=52)
button4.config(height=21, width=52)


button1.pack(side='left', fill='both')
button2.pack(side='right', fill='both')
button3.pack(side='left', fill='both')
button4.pack(side='right', fill='both')
app = Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```

any suggestions?

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? You haven't added the call back functions for button press and what programs are you looking to trigger?

Comment: I have tried to use class App: and i have gotten nothing but errors

Comment: Im just trying to get the buttons to trigger the launch of programs like CCleaner, and Adwcleaner, etc. I added a command=self.openfile and couldnt get it to work

Comment: I don't see any class called Application being defined in your code, if you haven't defined any class, remove the line app = Application(root)

Comment: Yeah i removed that after i posted. Because I saw that it shouldnt have been there because it wasnt defined.

Comment: So i have to add the call back function for a button press then define the application?

Comment: refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43900066/open-another-tkinter-program-from-a-main-file

Answer (score 1):

Running a subprocess, and linking a callback to a tkinter button are two different things;

First, I'll address linking a callback:
here, we'll print `launching 1` in the console when you press the button.

```
import os
import subprocess
import tkinter as tk


def launch_1():             # function to be called
    print('launching 1')

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('750x650')
root.title('Launch Test')


button1 = tk.Button(root, text="Button1", command=launch_1)  # calling from here when button is pressed
button1.pack(side='left', fill='both')

root.mainloop()
```

---

### The output is:

```
launching 1
```

---

Now let's launch a subprocess; for instance pinging stack overflow.
[example taken from here.](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/os/subprocess-for-system-administrators)

```
import os
import subprocess

import tkinter as tk


def launch_1():
    print('launching 1')    # subprocess to ping host launched here after
    p1 = subprocess.Popen(['ping', '-c 2', host], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    output = p1.communicate()[0]
    print(output)

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('750x650')
root.title('Launch Test')


button1 = tk.Button(root, text="Button1", command=launch_1)
button1.pack(side='left', fill='both')

host = "www.stackoverflow.com"        # host to be pinged

root.mainloop()
```

---

### The output is now:

```
launching 1
b'PING stackoverflow.com (151.101.65.69): 56 data bytes\n64 bytes from 151.101.65.69: icmp_seq=0 ttl=59 time=166.105 ms\n64 bytes from 151.101.65.69: icmp_seq=1 ttl=59 time=168.452 ms\n\n--- stackoverflow.com ping statistics ---\n2 packets transmitted, 2 packets received, 0.0% packet loss\nround-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 166.105/167.279/168.452/1.173 ms\n'
```

---

You can add more buttons with more actions as you wish.